# trouble updating mysql record from modal

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I am having trouble with updating information from a bootstrap modal to mysql database using PDO.

I have tried a basic static approach but it doesn't seem to be working. I click on the 'edit' button to trigger the modal which displays information from the table however when i change the course_title it doesn't do anything even though the code seems right.

here is the code for the modal:

```
<div id="editModel" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update Record: </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="text-primary">Please make any changes and click 'update' to save or 'cancel' to return</p>
            <form id="updateForm" action="ManageCourses_UpdateSubmit.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="course_code" class="control-label">Course Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_code" readonly="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="course_title" class="control-label">Course Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_title">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button id= "update" value="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

php code:

```
    <?php

    if(!isset( $_POST['course_title'], $_POST['course_code']))
    {
echo = 'invalid data has been sent';
    }

     include "db_conx.php";

     try
    {
$db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "UPDATE course_details SET course_title = :course_title,  
WHERE course_code = :course_code";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':course_title', $_POST['course_title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':course_code', $_POST['course_code'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->execute(); 

/*** success message ***/
echo = 'record updated';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
   {
/*** fail message incase something went wrong ***/
        //$message = 'Unable to process your request. Please try again later';
echo = 'Unable to process your request. Please try again later';
    }
    }
     ?>
```

Any suggestions on how i can overcome this please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your form elements don't have `name` attributes, so they're probably not being submitted to the server:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_title">
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_title" name="course_title">
```

(The same fix should be applied to all form elements.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i have added the name attributes to both input forms but this has had no effect

Comment: @user90210: Debug it.  Where specifically is it failing?  Is the HTTP request being made?  Does it have the values you expect it to have?  What is the server's response?  Is there an error in the PHP logs?  Is the database being updated?  When you debug the PHP code, where does its behavior differ from what you expect?  Don't treat the whole thing like a black box.  You own the code, you can debug it.

Comment: the part which is failing is when i click the 'update' button it should update the corresponding values in the mysql database however it does nothing. after checking logs, the correct values are being displayed in the form however nothing is being sent to the database. There are no errors either which is why it is very confusing. thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user90210: Well, looking at that `catch` block I don't think you can say with any certainty that there are no errors.  You ignore the `$e` value (which *contains* the error), the `$message` assignment is commented out (if it's even used at all afterward, which I can't know), and then you try to assign to `echo` which is either a syntax error or just isn't going to do anything.  So there very well *could be* an error that this code is simply ignoring.

Comment: you were right about the php file. I've corrected that, was missing a few things because it was a template. however even after making those changes the console isn't picking up any errors :/

Comment: @user90210: Are the PHP logs showing any errors?  Is the HTTP request being made correctly?  What is the server's response?  I really can't debug this for you.  You have to determine more specifically where the code is failing.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I am learning how to use the safari web inspector. I'm a new mac user so hoping this will shed some light as to why it isn't working. No errors regarding the functionality I'm looking at are being shown and the isn't a http server response either. It just stays on the modal

Comment: @user90210: If no HTTP request is being made at all then the form isn't posting to the server.  So the server-side code isn't being invoked at all.  Is there maybe some JavaScript which is preventing the form from posting?

Comment: I have some bootstrap javascript in my page which is used to load the modals, maybe that could be preventing it from talking to the server?

Comment: @user90210: Possibly, I really can't know.  To be honest, it sounds like you've got more work to do on the matter outside the scope of this question :-\